# MATLAB reshaping of matrix

Tags: matlab

Hi guys i'm relatively new to MATLAB and am trying to reshape the matrix i currently have. I have a matrix of 12*14*6400 and am trying to reshape it to 1200*14*64 where the second dimension remains untouched and there are 1200 windows (1st dimension) of 64 numbers in my 3rd dimension rather than 12 windows of 6400 numbers. I thought about just using

```
raw = permute(raw,[1,3,2]);
reshape = permute(reshape(raw, 1200, 64, 14), [1 3 2]);
```

but i don't think that's the right way to do it. When i tried running it i get "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you run the code more than once. When you run `reshape(raw, 1200, 64, 14)`, Matlab does not call the function `reshape` but the variable.

Remove the `reshape` variable from the Matlab workspace. Bring back the original `raw` variable and then, run the following:

```
raw = permute(raw,[1,3,2]);
newmat = permute(reshape(raw, 1200, 64, 14), [1 3 2]);
```

It is important to avoid using function names as a variable. Other than that, your code seems correct

Comment: Thanks! You were right about the problem being matlab calling the variable. I was thinking that it was strange as I was able to run the program the first time but it failed subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a first step.

```
raw=rand(12,14,6400);
raw=reshape(raw,[1200,14,64]);
```